# Python call async function from normal function in thread

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have an async function that I call from a normal function that I put in a thread. I don't know how to call the async function from the normal function, I have read the documentation on asyncio and looked this up but I can't find an answer that fits what I need. 
Here is some of my code:

```
    ...
    server_id = input("server id: ")
    @client.event

    async def on_ready():
      #called when app is ready
      send_msg = threading.Thread(target=send_server)
      send_msg.start()

    def send_server():
      #get input and send it to server (with async function)
      server = client.get_guild(int(server_id))
      message = input("Message to send: ")
      await server.channel.send(message)
```

And the error I get:

```
SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Is there a reason `send_server` is called from a separate thread? Genuine question, since there may be some constraints that you didn't share here. But my initial instinct is that, IME, threading and async don't really mix and that, for most I/O bound tasks in Python, you should be going for async and trying to stay away from threads.

Comment: I am running this for a discord bot, the main loop has to keep a connection with the discord servers and listen for messages. If I ran this without threading it would pause the whole loop.

Comment: You should be able to have your function do `await asyncio.sleep(xxx)` to delay without blocking the whole.